# I want to count empty and non empty files in a directory with use of loop, without using find command

Tags: linux, bash, files, scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in manu; do
  if [ -f $i ] && [ -s $i ]; then
    echo " $(ls $i | wc -l) non-empty files"
  elif [ -f $i ] && [ ! -s $i ]; then
    echo " $(ls $i | wc -l) empty files"
  fi
done
```

Output of this script is:

```
1 non-empty files
1 empty files
1 non-empty files
1 empty files
1 empty files
1 empty files
```

... and the output should be:

```
2 non-empty files
4 empty files
```

I don't know where I'm going wrong. Can anybody help me?

Comment: `for i in manu` executes exactly one iteration, setting `i` equal to `"manu"`.

Comment: `ls $i | wc -l` counts the number of lines in the listing of the file's name. It will produce `0` if the file doesn't exist (because `ls` then prints an error message to the error stream, and nothing on the output stream) or `1` if the file exists, regardless of that file's size.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure why you use `ls`.  The `ls` utility is usually used for listing the files in a directory.  Here you want to loop over files, which is easiest done with a file globbing pattern and a `for` loop.

You also output something that looks like it should be a summary, but you do that in each iteration rather than at the end.

I'm assuming that `manu` is a directory in the current directory and that you want to count the number of empty and non-empty files in that directory.  I furthermore assume that you don't want to count any other filetype than *regular* files.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob dotglob

nonempty=0
empty=0

for name in manu/*; do
    if [ -f "$name" ] && [ ! -h "$name" ]; then
        # $name is a regular file

        if [ -s "$name" ]; then
            nonempty=$(( nonempty + 1 ))
        else
            empty=$(( empty + 1 ))
        fi
    fi
done

printf 'There were %d empty files and %d non-empty files\n' "$empty" "$nonempty"
```

The `nullglob` shell option stops the loop from running even once if the pattern `manu/*` does not match anything, and the `dotglob` shell option allows the pattern to match hidden names too.

In each iteration, we then determine whether the current file is a regular file (the `-h` test tests for a symbolic link) and then whether it is empty or not.  We update one of two counters depending on the outcome of the `-s` test.  The result is shown at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Loops are generally the wrong way to do things in shells.

Here, you could pipe a directory listing command (`ls`) to a counting command (`awk`):

```
LC_ALL=C ls -Aqn manu/ | LC_ALL=C awk '
  /^-/ {if ($5 == 0) empty++; else non_empty++}
  END {printf "%d empty files\n%d non-empty files\n", empty, non_empty}'
```

Where `LC_ALL=C` disables localisation, so we're sure to get a standard and consistent `ls` output, and any sequence of bytes (as filenames are) form valid text.

`ls -n` lists the entries of the `manu` directory in long format which includes the type and size of the files, `-q` guarantees one line per file even if the file names (or symlink targets) contain newline characters and `-A` includes all entries, even hidden ones (not `.` nor `..` which are of no use here).

Then `awk` can just check the file type (first character being `-` means it's a regular file) and 5<sup>th</sup> field is the size.

Add a `-L` option to `ls` for the type and size of file to be considered *after* symlink resolution. With GNU `ls`, you can add `-U` to disable sorting which we don't care for here.

Or you can use `zsh` and its advanced globs:

```
empty=(manu/*(NDoN.L0))
non_empty=(manu/*(NDoN.L+0))
print "$#empty empty files\n$#non_empty non-empty files"
```

Where the `.` glob qualifier selects *regular* files, `L0` those of length 0 and `L+0` those of length greater than 0 (and `N` for `nullglob` (don't complain if there's no match), `D` for `dotglob` (includes hidden files), `oN` do `N`ot `o`rder the result).